# Writing twig tag that relies on another tag

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to create a twig tag that can be used as follows:

```
{% set_domain "zip-recipes" %}
...
...
{% trans "Ingredients" %}
...
{% trans "Ingredients" %}
```

`trans` tag would required domain set in `set_domain` tag.

I'm created the node and parser for `set_domain` to add the domain to `$context`:

```
class Project_TransDomain_Node extends \Twig_Node
{
    public function __construct($domain, $line, $tag = null)
    {
        parent::__construct(array(), array('domain' => $domain), $line, $tag);
    }

    public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write('$context[\'trans_domain\'] = "' . $this->getAttribute('domain') . '"')
            ->raw(";\n")
        ;
    }
}

class TransDomain_TokenParser extends \Twig_TokenParser
{
    public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
    {
        $parser = $this->parser;
        $stream = $parser->getStream();

        $domain = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();
        $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

        return new Project_TransDomain_Node($domain, $token->getLine(), $this->getTag());
    }

    public function getTag()
    {
        return 'set_domain';
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to access that in the `node` for `trans`.

I tried this but it doesn't evaluate the `$context['trans_domain']`:

```
class Project_Trans_Node extends \Twig_Node
{
    public function __construct($string, $line, $tag = null)
    {
        parent::__construct(array(), array('string' => $string), $line, $tag);
    }

    public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $string = $this->getAttribute('string');
        $domainExpr = $context['trans_domain'];

        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write("echo __('${string}','")
            ->repr('$context["trans_domain"]')
            ->raw("'")
            ->raw(";\n")
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony already has a [`trans_default_domain`](http://symfony.com/doc/3.0/reference/twig_reference.html#trans-default-domain) tag (since 2.1), just use that.

> You can set the translation domain for an entire Twig template with a single tag:
>
> `{% trans_default_domain "app" %}`
>
> Note that this only influences the current template, not any "included" template (in order to avoid side effects).

Comment: My bad on tagging #symfony2. I'm not using symfony.

Comment: I don't know twig enough to help, but you can look at Symfony's code to get some inspiration. You can find the code in [TwigBridge](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/v3.1.0/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig). What I can see from that it does not set the domain on the context, but directly on trans nodes ([TranslationDefaultDomainNodeVisitor.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.1.0/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/NodeVisitor/TranslationDefaultDomainNodeVisitor.php))